# Decreasing a number by 1

Tags: c#

I have an enum

```
enum MyEnum
{
  a=1,
  b=2,
  c=3
}
```

I set a variable to this enum for example

```
MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.b
```

I then decrement this value by one in my code

So,

if an enum was set to c (3) it would now be set to b (2)

If an enum was set to b (2) it would now be set to a (1)

What I was looking for was a neat way of saying

If an enum was set to a (1) it would now be set to c (3)

I want a short succinct way of making this decrement relationship circular.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What do you mean by a circular relationship? And how can you go from 3 to 1 if you decrement only by one? Are you talking about the relationship through a loop?

Comment: Why are you starting your enums at 1 instead of zero?

Comment: I guess I could start from 1, does it make a difference?

Comment: In the general case you would have to use the GetValues method. Values need not be dense and multiple names may be assigned to a single value.  `enum TrafficLightColors { Red = 0, Yellow = 1, Green = 2, First = 0, Last = 2, Blue = 42 };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Succinct is totally different from understandable in this scenario:

```
(MyEnum)((((int)myEnum+1) % 3) + 1)
```

**Explanation**

First, this expression is casting the enum to it's integer representation. Then, it's subtracting 1 to rebase the enum values at 0 so that the module operator (`%`) works. Then it's performing the subtract operation you mentioned (-1). In order to avoid negative operands, it adds 3 which will have no effect after applying the modulus operation. Combining those three operations is the same as adding 1. After that, it performs the module operation, achieving the circular properties you're looking for. Then it rebases the values to start at 1 again (by adding 1), and finally is casting the resulting number back to a MyEnum.

**What happens when the enum has more values?**

This expression assumes that your enum ends in 3. If you want to use it for enums with more items then you need to use a bit of reflection and you should probably extract it to a method:

```
MyEnum PreviousMyEnum(MyEnum myEnum)
{
    int maxValue = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().Max();
    return (MyEnum)((((int)myEnum -2 + maxValue) % maxValue) + 1);
}
```

Comment: It has to work for an enum with an arbitrary number of values.  Does this?

Comment: Agree with Sachin, using a hardcoded value for the number of enum values is just poor form.

Comment: What do the 2 and 3 represent here then?

Comment: `3` is the number of values in the enum; `2` is the length minus 1. Note that the enum int values need to be exactly in order for this to work.

Comment: @SachinKainth I added an extended explanation. What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: Well, if you have an enum with 4 values say, and your current enum value is 2.  Then you have this calculation ((2-3)%4)+1=((-1)%4)+1=-1+1=0.  It should equal 1

Comment: @SachinKainth I added a method that works for the general case.

Comment: This works for all cases except when the current value is 1.  Again lets use the example of a 4 value array: ((1-2)%4) + 1 = 0.  It should be 4.

Comment: @SachinKainth Sorry, I forgot about the cumbersome behavior of negative values in the modulus operation. Try with the new expression. It should avoid negative numbers.

Comment: @SachinKainth The first -1 is to rebase the values to 0, the second one is the subtract operation you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use a conditional. It's very clear and not especially verbose.

```
myEnum = myEnum==MyEnum.a ? MyEnum.c : (MyEnum)(int)myEnum-1;
```

It's easy enough to use Enum.GetValues() to make this generic. The concrete example above gets the idea across most clearly I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
int howManyYouWant = 20;

  //just get the enum values...
IEnumerable<MyEnum> someEnums = Enum
  .GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
  .Cast<MyEnum>();

  //figure out how many times we go through the whole set to meet desired amount
int numberOfRepeats = 1 + (howManyYouWant / someEnums.Count());

IEnumerable<MyEnum> manyEnums = Enumerable
  .Repeat(someEnums.Reverse(), numberOfRepeats)    //repeat the reverse of the set
  .SelectMany(x => x)    //unpack those sets into one set.
  .Take(howManyYouWant);  //and take what you wanted.

foreach(MyEnum x in manyEnums)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would help